# How to hide first parameter in recyclerview adapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

How do I hide the first parameter, so it can't be seen by the user. this is my json data

```
{
    "api_status": 1,
    "api_message": "success",
    "api_authorization": "You are in debug mode !",
    "data": [  
        {
            "id": 7,
            "title": "judul5",
            "file": "materipramugari.pdf",
            "isi_materi": "<p>dfs</p>",
            "created_at": "2020-02-04 13:46:41",
            "updated_at": "2020-02-04 13:46:42"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "title": "judul4",
            "file": "materipramugari.pdf",
            "isi_materi": "<p>asdasd</p>",
            "created_at": "2020-02-04 13:46:26",
            "updated_at": "2020-02-04 13:46:26"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "title": "judul3",
            "file": "materipramugari.pdf",
            "isi_materi": "<p>asdasd</p>",
            "created_at": "2020-02-04 13:46:08",
            "updated_at": "2020-02-04 13:46:08"
        },
    ],
    "api_http": 200
}
```

And this is my adapter:

```
class AdapterAuthor (var item: ArrayList<ModelAuthor>?, val ctx: Context)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterAuthor.ViewHolder>(){

    lateinit var sesionDayNight: SesionDayNight
    lateinit var sharedPrefDetailBerita : SharedPrefDetailBerita

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_olahraga, parent, false)
        sesionDayNight = SesionDayNight(parent.context)
        sharedPrefDetailBerita = SharedPrefDetailBerita(parent.context)
        return ViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return item!!.size
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val data = this.item?.get(position)

        val hitam = Color.parseColor("#3D3939")
        val putih = Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")

        val ids = data?.idberita!!.get(position)
        Glide.with(ctx).load(data.image).placeholder(R.drawable.logo3).into(holder.img)
        holder.judul.text = data.idberita
        holder.subjudul.setHtml(data.subtitle,  HtmlHttpImageGetter(holder.subjudul))

        val tgl = data.tanggal
        rawSimpleDate(tgl)
        val current = LocalDateTime.now()
        val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMMM yyyy")
        val formatted = current.format(formatter)

        if (rawSimpleDate(tgl).contains(formatted)){
            holder.tanggal.text = "Hari ini " + rawSimpleTime(tgl)
        }else{
            holder.tanggal.text = "Update At "+ rawSimpleDate(tgl)
        }


    }

    inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val base : CardView = view.findViewById(R.id.base_list_olahraga)
        val detail : LinearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.clic_rc_olahraga)
        val img: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.img_olahraga)
        val judul: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_judul_olahraga)
        val subjudul: HtmlTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.wv_subtitle_olahraga)
        val tanggal: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_tanggal_olahraga)
    }

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    private fun rawSimpleTime(timeRaw: String?): String {
        val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
        var time: Date? = null
        try {
            time = formatter.parse(timeRaw)
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        if (time != null) {
            val formatter_show = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm")
            return formatter_show.format(time)
        }

        return ""
    }

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    private fun rawSimpleDate(dateRaw: String?): String {
        val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
        var date: Date? = null

        try {
            date = formatter.parse(dateRaw)
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        if (date != null) {
            val formatter_show = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy")
            return formatter_show.format(date)
        }
        return ""
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `first parameter`?

Comment: i don't want to display the first data array from gson

Comment: **onBindViewHolder** function gives the position.. You can skip the 1st item when position is **0**

Comment: When you are passing a list to adapter then at that time remove 1st item from the list and pass to your adapter.

Comment: can you give me an example, I always fail to take the position of the item

Answer (score 0):

inside **onBindViewHolder** write a condition like

```
if(position!=0){ 
// Continue operation
}
```

So it skips the 1st item and binds other items. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in many ways

1. Remove first item from list at the time of adapter binding
2. Return empty view from onBindViewHolder when position is 0
3. Hide view inside onBindViewHolder when position is 0

   ```
   if (position == 0) {
      holder.itemView.visibility = GONE
   } else {
      holder.itemView.visibility = VISIBLE
   }
   ```